# We have two tags for the Quest Joint Airlock

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

[quest](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quest) and [quest-joint-airlock](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quest-joint-airlock) both refer to the Quest Joint Airlock. How should we handle these synonyms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Whistling.* No, there's only one tag, [quest-joint-airlock](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quest-joint-airlock). *Walks away, still whistling*.